# ODBC Drivers Missing on Windows Sever 2003 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-server-2003, 64-bit, odbc

I am working on a Windows Server 2003 x64 bit OS. Under ODBC connections, I am seeing only "SQL Server" and "SQL native Client". I wanted to make a datasource for `xls`.

I have already performed the following things and there is no solution:

1. Gone through the reply specified in [JET and ODBC driver missing, can not get data from MDBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435270/jet-and-odbc-driver-missing-can-not-get-data-from-mdbs) but there is no solution for me. I think the link solves the problem for a 32 bit OS.
2. Installed MDAC 2.8

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no 64 bit JET ODBC driver. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957570

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. Just to keep you updated, I already have Excel installed on my system. Even after that I was not able to create Excel ODBC driver from Administrative Tasks menu in Control Panel.

I just found a way to create the same and though of updating the forum. I have gone thorugh [64 Bit ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html). It says that, we will need to use the following command to achieve the ODBC connection for Excel files : `%windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) pack.  It includes ODBC drivers for Access and Excel.

Or you might look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052009501033.aspx  It explains that the excel 2003 drivers are installed when you install excel.

And, finally, check out [this post](http://www.devprise.com/2008/06/10/excel-odbc-driver-for-windows-server-2008/) about using the Excel ODBC driver in 64 bit windows.

Comment: As a last ditch step, just install Excel on the server.